# Google Custom Search Query Parameters and Category Parameters

Tags: google-custom-search

So I'm trying to set the query parameters and category parameters for google custom search. Here is an example search results page url:

```
http://www.whiterootmedia.com/search_results/index.html?q=my%20search%20phrase
```

So it looks like the default query parameter is `q` so I put `q` in the box when setting up the analytics portion for my google custom search engine. Is this ok?  I read it wasn't ok to use `q` but to instead use `query`? And why does it matter?

Also should I set a category parameter that looks to be optional.

Thanks,
Dusty

Answer (score 1):

The Google Search API just uses `q`. AFAIK the API doesn't have a `query` parameter. Check out the [custom search API documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#query-params).

Not sure what you mean by the 'category' parameter. Haven't come across that one before.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<gcse:search gname='google1'></gcse:search>
```

Javascript:

```
window.google.search.cse.element.getElement("google1").execute("hello world");
```

But you need to [wait for the Google script](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#javascript) to load before launching the javascript.

If you use searchresults-only instead of search, you also need to enable the correct layout in the CSE Control Pannel: https://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 1):

You can hit the following: https://cse.google.com/cse?as_q=your_query_string%20must_be_urlencoded&client=google-csbe&cx=full_cse_id_goes_here:including_the_bit_after_the_colon

So a direct answer to your question - the query parameter key is 'as_q'.

Comment: link isn't working... 1) please provide proper links. 2) if you provide link as an answer, please at least describe it will help.

Comment: Of course the link isn't working - I'm not about to give you my CSE's ID...

That's the *FORMAT* of a link that does work. Fill in the template bits, and you'll get results back.